# Using with variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, using

I know that the following code compile:

```
template<class Type>
class Foo
{
    using type = Type;
};
```

now, I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
template<class Type, class... OtherTypes>
class Foo
{
    using type = Type;
    // using types = OtherTypes;
    // using... types = OtherTypes;
    // using types... = OtherTypes;
    // using types = OtherTypes...;
    // using types... = OtherTypes...;
};
```

I tried all of the options of the code in comments, but none of them compile.
How can I fix it?

Comment: you can't. But depending on the use you can get alternate constructs

Comment: I need to get the variadic classes from Foo. Something like `Foo::OtherTypes`

Comment: would something like `using types_tuple = std::tuple<OtherTypes...>` be sufficient?

Comment: So you want to use the pack which Foo holds as a template argument after? or using it as the parameter list of a function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a pack of types as a type in a class.

The closest you can get is roughly:

```
template<class...Ts> struct types_t { constexpr types_t(){}; };
template<class...Ts> constexpr types_t<Ts...> types{};
```

these are values and types that represent a package of types.

```
template<class Type, class... OtherTypes>
class Foo
{
  using type=Type;
  using types=types_t<OtherTypes...>;
};
```

then we can write helper functions that consume bundled-up types and use them elsewhere.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class Types>
struct apply_types;    
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct apply_types<Z, types_t<Ts...>> {
  using type=Z<Ts...>;
};

template<template<class...>class Z, class Types>
using apply_types_t = typename apply_types<Z,Types>::type;
```

now `apply_types< some_template, some_types_t >` takes the types in the bundle and passes them to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to use the pack as template argument. Then you can try the following approach.

```
#include <utility>

template <class... Types>
struct Foo {};

template <template <class...> class Template,
          class... Types,
          template <class...> class T>
Template<Types...> foo(const T<Types...> &);

template <template <class...> class Template, class T>
using Type = decltype(foo<Template>(std::declval<T>()));

int main() {
  using T = Foo<int, int>;

  // As template argument
  using Tuple = Type<std::tuple, T>;
  static_assert(std::is_same<Tuple, std::tuple<int, int> >::value, "");

  return 0;
}
```